# More pythonic way to nest functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, easygui

Here is the code that I have:

```
def reallyquit():
        from easygui import boolbox
        if __debug__: print ("realy quit?")
        answer = boolbox("Are you sure you want to Quit?")
        if answer == 1:
            sys.exit()
        return

columns = ['adr1','adr2','spam','spam', 'spam']

Street = choicebox("Street Address?", title, columns)
    while Street == None:
        reallyquit()
        Street = choicebox("Street Address?", title, columns)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to recursively ask a question if a user closes a box inadvertently? Mainly looking for tips on the last 4 lines, but feel free to critique the rest.

Comment: I don't see any recursion.

Comment: There are many non-pythonic aspects to your formatting, and using `== None:` is not pythonic either (use `is None:` instead). Please consider checking your source with `pep8` or `flake8`. Or directly run `yapf` on the source.

Comment: Af few general pointers:  1.  Don't import inside a function unless it is required (which is rare but does happen), keep your imports at the top of the file.  2.  You don't need a "return" at the end of the function `reallyquit` since Python functions return None by default.  3.   Indent (and verify formatting of) your code on SO.  4.  What @Anthon said.

Comment: Also, you should not name your variables starting with an upper case letter. They could conflict with class names.

Comment: And don't make one-line conditionals like `if __debug__: print("really quit?")`, that should be two separate lines.

Comment: Since there is nothing "wrong" with this code, it may be better to ask this question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import sys
from easygui import boolbox, choicebox

def reallyquit():
    "Ask if the user wants to quit. If so, exit."
    if __debug__: 
        print("really quit?")
    answer = boolbox("Are you sure you want to Quit?")
    if answer == 1:
        sys.exit()

columns = ['adr1', 'adr2', 'spam', 'spam']
street = None

# ask for address until given or user decides to quit
while street is None:
    street = choicebox("Street Address?", title, columns)
    if street is None:
        reallyquit()
```

In the main logic: Usually you would not test if a value is equal to `None`, since it is a singleton (only one in the system, and all occurrences of `None` are to the same logical `None`). Thus `is None` is a better test. I've also used a little more Pythonic code formatting (spaces after commas in a list, lowercase variable names), and a test order that doesn't duplicate the user interaction call.

An alternative form suggested by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102441/eric) would be something like:

```
while True:
    street = choicebox("Street Address?", title, columns)
    if street is not None:
        break
    reallyquit()
```

This has the virtue of not repeating the `street is None` test, but is a bit longer. Your preference for which option seems clearer and more logical may vary.

For the preparations: Imports are taken out of functions, and `choicebox` is imported where it was previously missing. The function is given
a defining comment string. The one statement per line standard is enforced. And the unnecessary `return` removed.

This is still a fairly coarse program, but it's now "more Pythonic."

Not to be overwhelming, but the standard for Pythonic code appearance is [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). There are tools such as [pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) you can install to check compliance. The deeper or "semantic" part of Pythonic code is sketched out in [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), also known as "The Zen of Python." There is, sadly, no tool to judge compliance with those deeper principles. Experience is required.

Comment: just notice your indentation of the last line `reallyquit()` is 3, should be 4

Comment: Repeating the `street is None` condition here is not great - perhaps just do `while True`, and add a break to the if? That's the recommended way to emulate a `do while` statement in python

Comment: If line count really matters to you, `if street is not None: break` `reallyquit()` cuts one more off

Comment: @Eric It's really overall clarity that matters most. Line count is just one component. But I updated the alternate option with your `is not None` suggestion. It seems crisper. And that infinite-loop-plus-break should be able to put its best foot forward.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more idiomatic than using a sentinel variable:

```
while True:
    street = choicebox("Street Address?", title, columns)
    if street is None:
        reallyquit()
    else:
        break
```

Also, consider using the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module for your debug printing, so instead of `if __debug__: print(whatever)` you just have `logging.debug(whatever)` and set the logging level.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a break.